# Why do partitioned tables in PostgreSQL take locks on other tables when being dropped?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

This is using PostgreSQL 10.4

I have a partitioned table setup as:

```
                            Table "public.foo_partitioned"
   Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |    Default
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------
 bar_id             | integer                     |           | not null |
 ...
Partition key: LIST (bar_id)
Number of partitions: 10 (Use \d+ to list them.)
```

There is a foreign key on bar_id that references the table bars.

When I try to drop a partition, `foo_partitioned_1`, and if an outstanding idle transaction query exists on `bars`, the drop blocks. This seems very strange to me, that a drop on this partition wouldn't be allowed with a query against a separate table. I tried with detaching the partition first which also doesn't work. I can query the lock tables and get information like:

```
  pid  |   usename   | blocked_by |       blocked_query
-------+-------------+------------+----------------------------
 59897 | my_user | {59888}    | DROP TABLE foo_partitioned_1
```

When I run the following

```
select pgl.*, relname from pg_locks pgl join pg_class pgt on pgl.relation=pgt.oid  where pid=59897;
```

I get:

```
 locktype | database | relation |...| virtualtransaction |  pid  |        mode         | granted | fastpath |                 relname
----------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 relation |    16401 |     2620 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t        | pg_trigger
 relation |    16401 |     2608 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | RowExclusiveLock    | t       | t        | pg_depend
 relation |    16401 |   940755 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | f        | foo_partitioned
 relation |    16401 |   941051 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | f        | uq_foo_partitioned_1
 relation |    16401 |   742405 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessExclusiveLock | f       | f        | bars
 relation |    16401 |     2702 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessShareLock     | t       | f        | pg_trigger_oid_index
 relation |    16401 |   941047 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessShareLock     | t       | f        | foo_partitioned_1
 relation |    16401 |   941047 |...| 7/758              | 60266 | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | f        | foo_partitioned_1
```

The only lock not granted to the query is the one on `bars`. However, it's completely unclear to me why this lock is even required.

Thanks for all thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with partitioning.

Foreign keys are implemented as triggers in PostgreSQL, and when you drop the partition, the trigger on `bars` that implements (one half of) the foreign key has to be dropped.

Now dropping a trigger requires an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, and that blocks until all concurrent transactions on the table have finished.